# How to run v-network-graph?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am a beginner learning javscript and vue. I am trying to use v-netwok-graph in my PC. https://github.com/dash14/v-network-graph
Following instructions in the github repo, I have installed v-network-graph. Following are my js and vue files. But my app is not working.

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-network-graph
    class="graph"
    :nodes="nodes"
    :edges="edges"
  />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
 
  data () {return {
    nodes,
    edges
  }}
}
const nodes = {
    node1: { name: "Node 1" },
    node2: { name: "Node 2" },
    node3: { name: "Node 3" },
    node4: { name: "Node 4" },
  }
  const edges = {
    edge1: { source: "node1", target: "node2" },
    edge2: { source: "node2", target: "node3" },
    edge3: { source: "node3", target: "node4" },
  }
</script>

<style>
.graph {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import VNetworkGraph from "v-network-graph"
import "v-network-graph/lib/style.css"
import App from './App.vue'
// app.use(VNetworkGraph)


// createApp(App).mount('#app')
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(VNetworkGraph)
app.mount("#app")
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "samplevue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
app.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')
    at renderSlot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?06c8:2953:1)
    at eval (VNetworkGraph.vue?b3b1:59:1)
    at normalizeChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?06c8:6947:1)
    at createBaseVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?06c8:6697:1)
    at _createVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?06c8:6799:1)
    at createVNodeWithArgsTransform (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?06c8:6655:1)
    at Proxy.If (VNetworkGraph.vue?b3b1:51:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:890:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5598:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:185:1)
```

Comment: there's no mistakes with your code.  it runs just fine in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-christian-dlff0n?file=/src/App.vue).  must be an issue with how you installed and/or configured your project.  can you share your `package.json` file contents?

Comment: I have included my package.json contents. I have not edited package.json file. It is the same as created by vue created appname command

Comment: according to your package.json file, `v-network-graph` is not installed.  you need to run `npm install v-network-graph` from your project's root directory.  If successful your package.json file will automatically update to list `v-network-graph` as a dependency, at which point your code should work.